# Не работает форма отправки email (html+php)

Tags: php, html, форма

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="send.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="number">
        <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

send.php

```
<?php
$email="xxxx@email.ua";
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$phone=$_POST['number']; 
mail($email, $name, $phone);
?>
```

Имеються простая форма, и простой код отправки. На почту ничего не приходит.

Comment: Для уточнения: работаю на OpenServer. Может это связано с тем, что с локал хоста не можна отправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenServer сохраняет отправляемые письма локально. Пойму в эту папку C:\openserver\userdata\tmp\email

Что бы отправлять почту на реальный ящик нужно настроить OpenServer (Настройки\Почта\SMPT сервер)

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно это так. По умолчанию, настоящая рассылка отключена, письма сохраняются в логи. Разобрался